# Неверный результат запроса

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT
         COUNT(m.idAnswerToQuestion) AS answers,
         COUNT(f.idQuestion) AS questions

        FROM detailtousers a
        LEFT JOIN question f ON f.QuestionIdUser = 80
        LEFT JOIN answertoquestion m ON m.AnswerToQuestionIdUser = 80
        WHERE a.idDetailToUsers = 80
```

выдает **answers = 2**, хотя в таблице **answertoquestion** одна запись с **AnswerToQuestionIdUser = 80**

Comment: LEFT join же, NULL тоже считается,

Comment: аххх да...тогда INNER JOIN

Comment: Хотя он мне не помог...есть другие варианты?

Comment: ну вместо COUNT() выведите * чтобы посмотреть что возвращается, всё что я могу вам сказать что count() считает строки, и COUNT(m.idAnswerToQuestion) будет видимо равен COUNT(f.idQuestion)

Comment: вот так ещё есть

COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])

>Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr values.

COUNT(DISTINCT) returns 0 if there were no matching rows.

а простой аргумент вроде только для GROUP

Comment: попробовал - все по-прежнему

Comment: сколько записей в каждой из таблиц? 2x1x1 даст две записи. 1x2x1 даст тоже две записи. а 10x15x16 даст 2400 записей, а не как хотелось бы наверное 16...

Comment: а вот такой запрос (для проверки) выдал правильный результат: SELECT COUNT( * ) AS answers
FROM answertoquestion
WHERE AnswerToQuestionIdUser =80
_________________
и второй тоже дал верный результат
SELECT
         COUNT(m.idAnswerToQuestion) AS answers
        FROM detailtousers a
        LEFT JOIN answertoquestion m ON m.AnswerToQuestionIdUser = a.idDetailToUsers
        WHERE a.idDetailToUsers = 80

Comment: @IOleg, вам сюда: [Соединить 3 MySql запроса в 1](http://hashcode.ru/questions/178068/query-соединить-3-mysql-запроса-в-1)

Answer (score 1):

Так у вас сами таблицы не связаны... Попробуйте добавить условия для связи a, f и m ?

Наверное, что-то вроде:

```
SELECT  COUNT(m.idAnswerToQuestion) AS answers,
        COUNT(f.idQuestion) AS questions
  FROM detailtousers a
  LEFT JOIN question f ON f.QuestionIdUser = 80 AND a.idDetailToUsers = f.QuestionIdUser
  LEFT JOIN answertoquestion m ON m.AnswerToQuestionIdUser = 80 AND f.QuestionIdUser = m.AnswerToQuestionIdUser
  WHERE a.idDetailToUsers = 80
```

Comment: тот же результат получил

Answer (score 0):

А в других таблицах сколько?
[О функции COUNT.](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_getting_summarizing_values.html)

Comment: в другой таблице question - 2 записи по совпадению

Comment: Я дал вам ссылку на описание функции COUNT, т.к. полагаю, что вы не вполне верно себе это представляете.
COUNT с аргументом вернет количество строк, у которых аргумент не NULL. Уберите COUNT и посмотрите на результат без него.
Что будет?